# Modify an array of items using multiple promises in angular route resolve

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-promise

In a route resolve, I need to make an API call and return an array of books which looks like:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Book name',
    authorId: 123
}
```

I then need to make another API call for each book in the books array to return the author name and add this to the book object.

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Book name',
    authorId: 123,
    authorName: 'Author Name'
}
```

I have the following so far, but it does not work as the authorPromise is only resolved after the books have already been returned. How can I split these promises up properly and modify the book object as intended?

```
resolve : {
    books: function ($stateParams, booksService, authorsService) {
        var books = [];
        var categoryId = $stateParams.categoryId;
        booksService.getBooksByCategory(categoryId)
            .then(function (response) {
                books = response.data;

                angular.forEach(books, function (book) {
                    var authorId = book.authorId;
                    authorsService.getAuthor(authorId)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        book.authorName = response.data.Name;
                    });
                });

                return books;
            });
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are two errors in your code:

- the factory function does not return any value, you should return the promise generated by `booksService`.
- In the callback of the first `then` call you are returning the array before any of the async call is completed, so it will be empty. To solve this you can use `$q.all()`, that is a function that accept an array of promises as an argument and create a new promise that only resolve when all the promises in the array are resolved.

Edited code

```
resolve : {
    books: function ($q, $stateParams, booksService, authorsService) {
        var books = [];
        var categoryId = $stateParams.categoryId;
        return booksService.getBooksByCategory(categoryId)
            .then(function (response) {
                books = response.data;
                var promises = [];

                angular.forEach(books, function (book) {
                    var authorId = book.authorId;
                    var promise = authorsService.getAuthor(authorId)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        book.authorName = response.data.Name;
                    });
                    promises.push(promise);
                });

                return $q.all(promises).then(
                    function (res) {
                        return $q.resolve(books);
                    }
                );
            });
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you explain in a bit more detail how to ensure the router waits for the second series of requests to complete? I think it's the same problem I was having in my original attempt. Thanks.

Comment: You are right. I missed the `then` on the returned promise. Edited the answer.